# Same dbs with different names on same server. Need a way to manage the db objects

Tags: sql-server, database-design, merge

**Background**

We are UK based and have a couple of databases: DbFront_UK and DbBack_UK. We have recently ventured into the US and now have 2 new Dbs: DbFront_US and DbBack_US. DbFront contains sprocs that perform cross db joins to DbBack and vice-versa. A US and UK database should never communicate.

The US code and Db changes were done very quickly and separate to the UK changes. Now I have a task to merge the codebase and dbs. Merging the code has been easy however, the dbs are way harder. There are many sprocs that join as **DbFront_UK.schema.table** so I can no longer have a single SP that I can deploy to both Dbs.

**Restrictions:**

All 4 of these databases are on the same server in Rackspace. There is no way to split them and I can have only 1 SQL instance.

**Question:**

What's the best way to deliver a single set of database objects that can be deployed and managed easily? We are continually enhancing our product so the likelihood of SP changes are high.

**Options:**

1. I can find all SPs and objects that reference the other Db and add a suffix to the SP, one for UK and one for US (so **sp_one** becomes doubled as **sp_one_UK** and **sp_one_US**). Then in my C# code, I can do `if UK call this SP, if US call this one`. The benefit here is that it's probably easier to identify what SP goes where and it will be easier for new developers to understand. The danger is that it is a lot of tedious work and is ugly, there would be SPs existing in the US dbs with a UK suffix that never get called. But we have the same set of Db objects for both environments
2. Leave them as-is. Sp1 on UK will still be named SP1 on US. The big danger here is that we end up duplicating changes and they will very easily get missed. There are a lot of developers here and these changes will likely get missed, future maintainability is an important factor
3. I can run sql in sqlcmd mode and have the Db name as a variable. I think this would effect the execution plan and could lead to poor SQL performance, thoughts around this would be appreciated.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trivial way to do this that I know of in SQL Server, however you can do this by, in the frontend database, creating a synonym for each table and/or SP in the backend database:

```
use TestStuff; -- My frontend db
create schema backend; -- or whatever schema you want
create synonym backend.EPValue for RCDEV.ops.EPValue -- RCDev is the backend
select * from backend.EPValue
```

Alternatively, you can create a view:

```
create view backend.EPValue as select * from RCDev.ops.EPValue
```

Then the SP's will use the synonym or view.

For Oracle, you can create a Database Link (can't remember the syntax, sorry) within each Front database to the appropriate back end, and the SP's use the Link name.

For other database types...well, specify which one you're using!

Comment: Thanks simon. Synonyms were mentioned earlier but disregarded for some reason. Looking into it now, this is exactly what I need. Thanks